# EF core 1-1 relation spawns new row everytime when main table is edited, instead of update current value

Tags: web-applications, ef-code-first, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I'm working on my first Web App (so iam not very experienced so far) and having a problem when main contact is being saved/edited from razor pages (CUD tasks) it spawns new row with ID in related table with value (same or null).

I have defined main contact class as:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Surename{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public int? Location_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Location_ID")]
    public Location Location{ get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int? PhonePrivate_ID { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("PhonePrivate_ID ")]
    public PhonePrivate PhonePrivate { get; set; }
}
```

And related table with Private Phone numbers as (this separation is on demand because of security reasons, it is not my idea):

```
public class PhonePrivate
{
    [Key]
    public int PhonePrivate_ID { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

When I firt definen PhonePrivate number in form edit/create it's relatively okay, it create new record in PhonePrivate Table with ID = 1 and Number from form even if it is null which should not create any record.

But when I want to change main contact field for example Name, it creates new PhonePrivate_ID with same value as it have before.

I also tryied fluent API definition like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PhonePrivate>().HasOne(a => a.ID).WithOne(b => b.PhonePrivate_ID);
```

but without any success.

I'm afraid that I misunderstood a relation definition in EF core examples, and I have relation badly configured.

How can I do the 1-1 optional relation? Or should I do 1-many relation with constraint on unique ID from other side which leads to forced 1-1 relation on side of DB ?

Comment: Are you mapping to existing database or the design of the entities and database tables can be changed?

Comment: Database is still seeded with sample data when doing on this bad relation issue, meanwhile I did an Export to excel functionality, and trying to do now import so I can later upload real data. But for now database can change with no problem :)